# How to iterate through indexed field to add field from another index

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm rather new to elasticsearch, so i'm coming here in hope to find advices. 
I have two indices in elastic from two different csv files.

The index_1 has this mapping:

```
{'settings': {
            'number_of_shards' : 3
    },
    'mappings': {
        'properties': {
            'place': {'type': 'keyword' },
            'address': {'type': 'keyword' },
        }
    }
}
```

The file is about 400 000 documents long.
The index_2 with a much smaller file(about 50 documents) has this mapping:

```
    {'settings': {
            "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    'mappings': {
        'properties': {
            'place': {'type': 'text' },
            'address': {'type': 'keyword' },
        }
    }
}
```

The field "place" in index_2 is all of the unique values from the field "place" in index_1. 
In both indices the "address" fields are postcodes of datatype keyword with a structure: 0000AZ.

Based on the "place" field keyword in index_1 I want to assign the term of field "address" from index_2.

I have tried using the pandas library but the index_1 file is too large. I have also to tried creating modules based off pandas and elasticsearch, quite unsuccessfully. Although I believe this is a promising direction. A good solution would be to stay into the elasticsearch library as much as possible as these indices will be later be used for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly it sounds like you want to use [updateByQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

the request body should look a little like this:

```
{
   'query': {'term': {'place': "placeToMatch"}},
   'script': 'ctx._source.address = "updatedZipCode"'
}
```

This will update the address field of all documents with the matched place.

EDIT:

So what we want to do is use [updateByQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) while iterating over all the documents in index2.

First step: get all the documents from index2, will just do this using the basic [search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) feature

```
{
   "index": 'index2',
   "size": 100 // get all documents, once size is over 10,000 you'll have to padginate.
   "body": {"query": {"match_all": {}}}
}
```

Now we iterate over all the results and use `updateByQuery` for each of the results:

```
// sudo
doc = response[i] 

// update by query request.
{
  index: 'index1',
  body: {
   'query': {'term': {'address': doc._source.address}},
   'script': 'ctx._source.place = "`${doc._source.place}`"'
  }
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for you answer. For more clarity, in index_1 the field "address" is a destination zipcode and in index_2 field "address" is the source zipcode. The field "place" in both indices corresponds to the source zipcode. So the objective is to add the source zipcodes to a new field in index_1 based on the "place" fields. I don't know if that's clear enough, if not let me know.

Comment: i edited my answer given a broader explanation, however the concept remains the same, use `update by query` method to update documents in index1 using their post code.

Comment: I've tried your solution but I keep getting syntax errors. Are you sure this syntax is python readable ? I'm using spyder, and I've tried modifying the code to get rid of the syntax errors but I keep bumping into new ones...

Comment: there is no syntax here, just the request body of the elastic request. the loop is obviously is missing as-well as the elastic request, i've written the request body but you need to fill in the blanks depending if you use an elastic library or curl

Comment: Indeed they are just the bodies but the syntax was coming from the bodies not my loops. But I found a way around that and managed to solve my issue. 
Thank you very much for your help and your time!